# Checking array variables against each other

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var carpets = [];
$.get("pullCarpets.php", function($carpets){
    $.each($carpets, function(i, item){
        console.log(item.id);
        for(var j = 0; j < carpetArray.length; j++){
            console.log(carpetArray[j];
            if(carpetArray[j] == item.id){
                list.push(item);
            }
        }
    });
}, "json");
console.log(carpets);
```

Basically I think everything is actually working as it should. But the arrays both the carpetArray and the object array pulled from the php file($carpets) are quite long, like a hundred or so variables in them. When I try to run the code I get an error message in the console saying error in javascript console, functionality might be affected. I'm guessing the console doesn't like showing me all the numbers, but for some reason when I run the function nothing happens.

Following this bit in the script is another $.each iterater that displays the content of carpets into a div, but it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *when I run the function nothing happens* - So you don't get any console output? Do you see the request?

Comment: You seem to be missing a ) on line 6

Comment: also, maybe you meant to do `carpets.push(item)` instead of `list.push(item)` ? note though that since you are making an ajax call, that last `console.log` is going to execute before the ajax call/response completes.. that's the nature of async

Comment: sorry I was in a rush writing the question the errors have been fixed and I think the problem was I wasn't running the following script inside the get command so it was being run before the callback or whatever. I've fixed it now, thanks though.

Comment: It could even be written `$.each($carpets, function(i, item){
            if(carpetArray.indexOf(item.id) !=-1) carpets.push(item);
    });`

Answer (score 1):

seems that you're missing a `)` on line 6 and `carpetArray` and `list` don't exist

```
var carpets = [];
var list = [];

$.get("pullCarpets.php", function($carpets){
    $.each($carpets, function(i, item){
        console.log(item.id);
        for(var j = 0; j < carpets.length; j++){
            console.log(carpets[j]);
            if(carpets[j] == item.id){
                list.push(item);
            }
        }
    });
}, "json");
console.log(carpets);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$carpet` with `data`.

And you are missing ")" on the console.log command.